# LLVM / Clang 8 Compilation of OpenMP Code in Windows

Tags: windows, compilation, clang, openmp, llvm

I'm using the Windows version of [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) (LLVM) 8 under Windows.
I'm compiling a code which uses [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP).

Under the `lib` folder of Clang there are 2 files which are OpenMP related:

1. `libomp.lib`.
2. `libiomp5md.dll`.

My questions are:

1. When I compile the code I use the flags `-Xclang -fopenmp` for the compiler. In in GCC and ICC using the flags tell the compiler to link the OpenMP library automatically. What about Clang? Does it do it automatically or must I link with `libomp.lib` manually? Is there a way to trigger automatic linking to the OpenMP library?
   **Answer**: This was answered in [Michael Klemm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2785280/michael-klemm)'s [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55981435/195787) - Use the `clang` driver both for compiling and linking and then the `-fopenmp` will work as in `GCC`.
2. When I link with `libomp.lib` manually (Defining as a library for the linker) the output `exe` requires `libomp.dll` while the supplied OpenMP Dynamic Library is `libiomp5md.dll`. Is that a bug or is it because I link manually?
   **Answer**: The `libomp.dll` is supplied in the `bin` folder and not the `lib` folder.
3. What's the proper way to utilize OpenMP in Clang under Windows? The `clang-cl` driver doesn't work with `/openmp` or `-openmp` as the MSVC's `cl` compiler.
   **Answer**: Currently it can be done either with `clang -fopenmp ...`, `clang-cl -Xclang -fopenmp ...` or `clang-cl /clang:-fopenmp ...` (Which is equivalent of `-Xclang -fopenmp`).

**Remark**
On Windows I use Windows Driver of Clang using `clang-cl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile and link OpenMP code with clang on Windows, you will have to pass `-fopenmp` to both the compiler and the linker:

```
clang -fopenmp -o bla.obj -c bla.c
clang -fopenmp -o bla.exe bla.obj
```

Comment: I don't think so on Windows - `lld-link: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -fopenmp` (This is the output of the procedure).

Comment: I was using the compiler driver to invoke the linker.  If you do it that way, the compiler driver will supply the linker with the right libraries when using `-fopenmp`.  If you want to invoke the linker yourself, please use -v with the compiler to find out what linker options the compiler driver uses.

Comment: OK. Then what `DLL` will the compiled EXE require? Could you check? Is it `libiomp5md.dll` or `libomp.dll`?

Comment: For  me: 
`"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.13.26128\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" -out:bla.exe -defaultlib:libcmt "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.13.26128\\lib\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.16299.0\\ucrt\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.16299.0\\um\\x64" -nologo -nodefaultlib:vcomp.lib -nodefaultlib:vcompd.lib "-libpath:C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin/../lib" -defaultlib:libomp.lib bla.obj`

Comment: My problem is it links with `libomp.lib` which requires `libomp.dll` while Clang supplies `libiomp5md.dll`. I need somehow to compile in a way it matches the supplied dynamic library of OpenMP which is `libiomp5md.dll`. Check the dependency of your `EXE` which `DLL` does it require for OpenMP?

Comment: With the mentioned command lines, my process only pulls in `libomp.dll`.

Comment: Which the problem I raised above. I'd like it to use `libiomp5md.dll` which is what supplied in `Lib` folder. There is another question if when running it will be compatible with Intel OpenMP (Which is the origin of the OpenMP in LLVM / Clang).

Comment: OK, then please state exactly what you want to achieve?  I stated that the proper way to use OpenMP with clang (on any platform) is to use `-fopenmp`. Are you trying to compile code that you can link with code from the Intel compiler?

Comment: Michael, Read (2) in my question. First of all `-fopenmp` doesn't work on `clang-cl`. It requires `-XClang -fopenmp`. At least in my system. Second, `libomp.lib` is by Intel as well. It has only different name. I want to compile with Clang yet make it require `libiomp5md.dll` (Which is what supplied in `lib` library of LLVM for Windows).

Comment: I have done the same with clang-cl: `clang-cl -v /clang:-fopenmp -o bla.exe bla.obj`. It still links with libomp.dll.  BTW, my installation of clang has both libomp.dll (which is the default name for the OpenMP runtime for clang) and a `libiomp5md.dll`, but it only provides a `libomp.lib`, which AFAIK is used to link against the corresponding `libomp.dll`.

Comment: The only way to link against `libiomp5md.dll` from clang's bin is to have the `libiomp5md.lib` from the Intel compiler and use that for linkage using an explicit linker command, either through the compiler driver w/o OpenMP flags or by invoking the linker directly.

Comment: This is what the whole question about. Why is the 'dll' of Intel OpenMP is supplied but not the 'lib'? Also, they are the same code, so will they be compatible loaded in parallel? By the I still don’t get how you trigger OpenMP with 'clang-cl' without 'Xclang'. Could you show the command line?

Comment: I cannot say why clang ships with `libiomp5md.dll`, but does not supply the .lib file with it.  The command line I was using is in my comment: `clang-cl -v /clang:-fopenmp -o bla.exe bla.obj`. If you are OK with the answer about `libiomp5md.dll` taking some more time, I can speak to my Intel colleagues about that part of the question.

Comment: Basically `libomp.lib` in LLVM / Clang should match exactly `libiomp5md.lib` of Intel as the code was contributed by Intel. Now the question what happens when the host uses `libiomp5md.dll` while my application uses `libomp.dll`. Will my application understand they are the same and hence there is no conflicts and no need to reload the functions? I'd be happy to hear your friend opinion on this.

Comment: So, `libiomp5md.dll` is a *copy* of `libomp.dll`.  This is for historic reasons, as initially, when clang started to use the OpenMP runtime, it linked against `libomp5md.dll`.  This was later changed to `libomp.dll` and clang maintains a copy of the old name for compatibility reasons.  So, it does not make a difference that you're linking against `libomp.dll`. If you want to have compatibility with the Intel Compiler's OpenMP runtime, then you will need to have a copy of Intel Parallel Studio installed and explicitly link against it's `libiomp5md.dll` using a custom link line.  Makes sense?

Comment: I knew `libomp.dll` is basically renamed Intel OpenMP (Read my remarks above). My question is whether it is compatible to work under applications which runs Intel OpenMP? Namely, does the name change cause issues with applications running?

Comment: This is what will happen: `OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libomp.dll already initialized.`  So, you cannot have both `libomp.dll` and `libiomp5md.dll` in the same process space.  If you want to mix compilers, you need make sure that either compiler (clang or icl) only uses one of the libraries.

Comment: I see. This is the error I was talking about. It is silly as the code is the same. I wish the LLVM people would make it work. Thank You.

Comment: Not sure if is this a problem that LLVM can solve or if this is a Windows problem with shared libraries (it's the same on Linux, BTW).  At least the OpenMP runtime detects the issue and tells you about it.  You can always explicitly link against `libiomp5md.dll` from the Intel Compiler or file a bug report against LLVM that `libiomp5md.lib` is missing, so that you cannot make the LLVM code compatible with the Intel Compiler.

Comment: I think they could have left the Intel naming and that't it. I totally agree. Marked your answer and +1. By the way, is using `clang-cl /clang:-clangflag` is equivalent of `clang-cl -Xclang -clangflag`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if that's equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

***Adding clarity to what the OpenMP libraries actually are, and how to use them on Windows with `clang-cl`***

libomp.dll and libiomp5md.dll ARE THE SAME FILES!

When compiling for Windows, you link against `libomp.lib` OR `libiomp5md.lib` which will link to the same-named DLL at runtime, i.e. `libomp.dll` OR `libiomp5md.dll` respectively.

If you load 2 files that use the "different-name DLL," the interpreter will crash and give you a nasty error like: **OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libomp.dll already initialized.**

Why?  Because the program has no idea they are the same DLL, they have different names, so it assumes they are different.  And it crashes.  For this reason only, you can choose to swap which OpenMP DLL you link to in your program.

If your program doesn't crash and give you an error, you can keep using the same link to OpenMP.  Otherwise, to silence the error, link to the one that is loaded by another program already.

If using `clang-cl.exe` which is the "drop-in" Clang replacement for MSVC `cl.exe` you should pass a compiler argument such as `-Xclang -fopenmp` which will convert the argument over to "Clang language."  Don't forget to still pass to the linker the OpenMP LIB you chose, because on Windows, it won't be automatic.

That's all I've learned as brief as possible about OpenMP linking on Windows.